# methods with state Groovy / Java

Tags: java, groovy

I have a bit of a long winded question. Say I have a method which makes a math calculation and this method needs to keep state (i.e. every time it gets called with parameters its result is affected by its previous results).

```
int sum

def add(int x, int y) {
 sum = sum + x + y
 return sum
}
```

On top of this, its state is dependent on where it was called. (i.e. if I call this method twice from different places the method must only work with its own state). I was thinking about Closures in groovy but closures doesn't keep state and if you store your state in a variable outside of the closure a second call to this method won't have its own state.

Lets also assume for reasons that I won't go into right now I cannot keep this method in a object to keep state. i.e.

```
class MyObject {
   private int sum

   MyObject() {}

   public int sum(int x, int y) {
     sum = sum + x + y
     return sum
  }
}
```

I want to avoid doing this

```
MyObject mObj = new MyObject()
.... some code later
def result = mObj.add(1,2)
```

instead I just want to have to do this

```
for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
    def result1 = add(1,2)
}
some code later
for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
    def result2 = add(1,2)
}
```

In the case above the two 'add' methods should have its own state.

Is there any other tricks in either groovy or java to achieve something like this?

Comment: “For reasons that I won’t go into right now I cannot keep this method in an object to keep state”: well, for reasons that I won’t go into now you won’t get a satisfying answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing here is a closure.  The Groovy code there does
already that.  If you want put that "global" state into the function, you
could be explicit about it and "build" the `add` function.  E.g.

```
def add = { ->
    def total = 0
    return { a, b -> 
        return total += a + b 
    }
}()

println(add(1,2))
// -> 3
println(add(1,2))
// -> 6
println(add(1,2))
// -> 9
```

Above code creates a function, that holds the state for `total` and
returns a closure, that does the actual add.  It captures the local
`total`.  Then this function is called and the result (the closure) is
assigned to `add`.

#### edit

As stated in the comments, the expectation is a "magic" boundary that
isolates the state of `add` over the course of the execution of the
program.  Assuming that this question aims for a DSL, users might be
able to know the implicit boundaries.  Yet I doubt there is a way with
Groovy (or Java?) to know, that a function is called from inside
a for-loop unless you write your own for.

One way around this would be to create an explicit boundary like this:

```
def withTotal(c) {
    def total = 0
    c.add = { total += it }
    c.call()
    total
}

println withTotal{
    add(1)
    add(2)
}
// -> 3

println withTotal{
    10.times{ add it }
}
// -> 45
```

Comment: At least to me it is _not_ clear, that you expect the add() in the final example to give the same result and therefor i think you could make that obvious by adding comments in your example, what results you expect. Also how should add work if it would have been called at the level of `some code later`? If you want to introduce new state at random points, you need to mark that - groovy/java will not magically _know_, that the code now is called inside a for loop.

Comment: If you call that builder again just before the second for, this works as you wish.  Each call gives you a fresh total and that is state to the then created closure, as it is only captured by that closure and no one else.

Comment: would it be possible to have something like the above but have, one for loop
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    withTotal{
        add(1)
}
    withTotal{
        add(2)
}
} so that each withTotal in side the for loop has its own scope and, on the second iteration that withTotal works with its original scope?